# SQL Server Built in SP's - Cliff Notes

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I hope We've all used **SP_HELP**.  I used **SP_HELPTEXT** today for the first time.  Mostlyl I learn these from co-workers who already know them or some random stackoverflow finding.

Is there some sort of exhaustive list on SQL Servers built in SP's and their function?  I may be writing more code than I have to.

Thanks for the help.

Matt

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [system stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx) and [system functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you. I beleive that answers my questions. @Pondlife make that an answer and I'll mark it answered.

Comment: I don't want to sound ungrateful or dismissive, but since your question was basically "where can I find documentation for system features in SQL Server", I can't really take credit for suggesting the obvious answer :-)

Comment: @Pondlife your humbleness is a good example on stack overflow.  Thanks for the help.  Obvious and all.